# about shell variables and environment variables

Tags: linux, shell

I'm reading Wrox, Beginning Linux Programming.
But I've got a question about shell variables.

Here is a shell script named test.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash
read test
echo $test
exit 0
```

Then I chmod the script:

```
$ chmod +x test.sh
$ ./test,sh
```

When I type "ok", it echos the "ok".

But when I returned to the shell interface, I typed:

```
$ echo $test
```

It returned nothing...

I don't know why $test doesn't return "ok" just like the script does...
And the book doesn't metion it...

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables only exist in the process where they were created (and also in child processes, if they are exported). Running a script creates a new process, after the script ends, all its variables are lost.

You can run the script without starting a new process by "sourcing" it:

```
. ./test.sh
```

You should remove the `exit` then, though, otherwise it will exit your current shell.

Answer (score 2):

It is because they are different processess, 
to "include" source of other script run

`. test.sh`

the test.sh should be without exit:

```
#! /bin/bash
read test
echo $test
```

Answer (score 1):

**Process locality**

> The values of environment variables are local, which means they are
>   specific to the running process in or for which they were set. This
>   means that if we open two terminal windows (which means we have two
>   separate bash processes running), and change a value of an environment
>   variable in one of the windows, that change will not be seen by the
>   shell in the other window or any other program currently on the
>   desktop.

For your more understanding : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables